# Subtract two CSV strings

Tags: ruby, csv, oop, data-structures

Given two CSV strings `foo_csv` and `bar_csv` with equal headers.

What is the best way to perform `foo_csv - bar_csv` while preserving the headers?

This is how I solved it:

```
foo_csv = <<~EOL
foo,bar,baz
cats,and,dogs
things,and,stuff
EOL

bar_csv = <<~EOL
foo,bar,baz
cats,and,dogs
EOL

x = CSV.parse(foo_csv)
y = CSV.parse(bar_csv)

headers = y.shift

p z = x - y
#=> [["foo", "bar", "baz"], ["things", "and", "stuff"]]
```

But I wonder if there is a better way. For example if I give `CSV::parse` or `CSV::read` the `headers: true` hash then I get a `#<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>` object back which I'm able to simply call `#headers` on.

```
CSV.parse(foo_csv, headers: true).headers
#=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

But the object doesn't have the subtraction method on it. I'm not so sure what I'm trading off when I choose to work with a regular array instead of a `CSV::Table`

However, I do have experience working with `Pathname` objects and I really love all the methods that come with it, so it makes me think maybe a solution that involves `CSV::Table` would be worth it if possible.

One way would be to just carry around `CSV::Table` objects and then call `#to_a` everytime I'm about to subtract.

Curious to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given these `CSV::Table` objects:

```
require 'csv'

x = CSV.parse(<<-CSV, headers: true)
foo,bar,baz
cats,and,dogs
things,and,stuff
CSV

y = CSV.parse(<<-CSV, headers: true)
foo,bar,baz
cats,and,dogs
CSV
```

You could extract the rows from table `y`:

```
y_rows = y.entries
#=> [#<CSV::Row "foo":"cats" "bar":"and" "baz":"dogs">]
```

And remove identical rows from table `x` via [`delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html#method-i-delete_if):

```
x.delete_if { |row| y_rows.include?(row) }
```

The result:

```
puts x
# foo,bar,baz
# things,and,stuff
```

Note that this is quite expensive because `include?` has to traverse the `y_rows` array for each row in `x`.

---

Another approach is to patch the `CSV` classes:

```
class CSV
  class Row
    def hash
      @row.hash
    end
    alias_method :eql?, :==
  end

  class Table
    def -(other)
      if other.is_a?(Table)
        self.class.new(@table - other.table)
      else
        self.class.new(@table - other)
      end
    end
  end
end

z = x - y

puts z
# foo,bar,baz
# things,and,stuff
```

`CSV::Table#-` creates a new table without the given rows or the rows of the given table. Due to the way `Array#-` works, it will also remove any duplicate rows.

The additions in `CSV::Row` are needed, because `Array#-` depends on a proper implementation of `hash` and `eql?`. Not sure why these are missing.

Comment: The second method works fine and is fast. No need to mention the first method IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

## CSV without newlines in cells

You could apply the [set difference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-2D) before creating the CSV Table.

By removing the first line of `bar_csv`, you keep the `foo_csv` header :

```
foo_without_bar_csv = (foo_csv.lines - bar_csv.lines.drop(1)).join

CSV.parse(foo_without_bar_csv, headers: true).each do |row|
  puts row.to_h
end
#=> {"foo"=>"things", "bar"=>"and", "baz"=>"stuff"}
```

## CSV with newlines in cells

If your CSV has newlines in cells (why???), the previous solution will work fine, as long as there is no partial match :

```
foo_csv = <<~EOL
foo,bar,baz
cats,and,dogs
please,"don't\nuse",newlines
EOL

bar_csv = <<~EOL
foo,bar,baz
please,"don't\nuse",newlines
EOL

#=> {"foo"=>"cats", "bar"=>"and", "baz"=>"dogs"}
```

But this will fail :

```
foo_csv = <<~EOL
foo,bar,baz
cats,and,dogs
please,"don't\nuse",newlines
EOL

bar_csv = <<~EOL
foo,bar,baz
please,"don't\nsmoke",here
EOL

#=> Illegal quoting in line 3. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
```

Comment: CSV data might contain newlines, i.e. a row may span multiple lines.

Comment: @akuhn: Comment removed. What I meant to say is that weird data leads to weird bugs. If you use an email address with escaped newlines and `"@"`, you shouldn't complain that programs don't accept your valid address. Instead of multiple lines in a CSV cell, more columns could be used.